# Attempted assignment to non-variable (error token is "= 0 ")

Tags: bash

Very new to this and pulling my hair out over here.  Help is appreciated.
Here's my error:

```
/home/rdmorgan0001/bin/dfchkr1.sh: line 12: -1922376 = 0 : attempted assignment to non-variable (error token is "= 0 ")
[rdmorgan0001@cset2 bin]$
```

Here's my script-

```
#!/bin/bash
#
#
#You need to create a dflog1.txt file from the /dev/sda1 folder before running this script...df | grep "home2" | awk '{print $3}' > dflog1.txt
#
#
x=($(cat dflog1.txt))                          #x will be the files size found in dflog1.txt which is our initial snapshot.
y=($(df | grep "home2" | awk '{print $3}'))                      #y will equal the current disk usage
z=100
echo $(( $x-$y )) > xy/xy.txt                     #make a file called xy.txt in the folder xy
w=($(cat xy/xy.txt))                         #w will now be equal to the number contained in xy.txt                   
if $(( $w = 0 ))                              #if w = 0, then there were no changes.
 then
   echo "There are no changes greater than 100MB at this time."
      exit
elif
   $(( $w != 0 ))                         #if it's not equal to zero then there were changes
  then
   $(( $w -lt 0 ))                           #if the change represented by w is a negative number
     $((  -1 * $w )) > absolute/wabs.txt     #then multiply it by -1 to get the absolute value of w
       a=($(cat absolute/wabs.txt))            #a is now equal to the absolute value of w
elif
   $(( $a -ge 100 ))
      then echo $w > dfchanges/dfchanges1$(date "+%d%m%y%H:%M").txt
        echo "Changes greater than 100MB have been detected.  Check the dfchanges1(date).txt file."
         df | grep "home2" > dflog1.txt       #remake our base comparison file since there were changes.
          exit
elif
   $(( $w -ge 100 ))  #changes greater than 100
    then echo $w > dfchanges/dfchanges1$(date "+%d%m%y%H:%M").txt
      echo "Changes great thatn 100MB have been detected.  Check the dfchanges1(date).txt file for more info"
        df | grep "home2" > dflog1.txt     #remake our base comparison file since there were chagnes.
elif
   $(( $a -lt $z ))                                 #if it's less than 100 we will disregard it in the next line
       then
         echo "There are no changes greater than 100MB at this time."
             exit
fi
```

Answer (score 4):

Inside `(( ... ))` arithmetic evaluation, `=` is an *assignment operator* not a *logical comparison* operator. So `$(($w = 0))` is dereferencing variable `w`, and then attempting to assign the value `0` to its *value*.

Probably what you intended was `if $(($w == 0))`. However  - although syntactically correct - the parameter expansion syntax `$w` is not necessary in this context so you could simplify that to `if ((w == 0))`, and similarly for `$(( $w != 0 ))` and so on. From the `ARITHMETIC EVALUATION` section of `man bash`:

> ```
> Shell  variables  are  allowed as operands; parameter expansion is per‐
> formed before the expression is evaluated.  Within an expression, shell
> variables  may  also  be referenced by name without using the parameter
> expansion syntax.
> ```

Also note that `-le`, `-gt` operators are for arithmetical comparison within `[ ... ]` or `[[ ... ]]` test brackets; within `(( ... ))` brackets (which are for arithmetic evaluation **only**), you should use `<=`, `>` and so on.

Comment: I switched line 13 to  $[ w== 0 ] (tried it with a $ before w as well) and it results in this message- /home/rdmorgan0001/bin/dfchkr1.sh: line 13: 0: command not found
/home/rdmorgan0001/bin/dfchkr1.sh: line 18: 1: command not found
/home/rdmorgan0001/bin/dfchkr1.sh: line 24: -ge 100 : syntax error in expression (error token is "100 ")

Comment: The `$[ . . . ]` form of arithmetic evaluation is deprecated and should not be used in new code - see for example http://stackoverflow.com/a/2415777/4440445